# Spark Dataframe is getting appended with Square Brackets while Saving As Text File

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, rdd

I am trying to save a dataframe in hadoop in append mode.

Below is the command:

```
df.repartition(5).map((row)=>row.toString()).write.mode(SaveMode.Append).text(op_dir)
```

Issue is that the data in the hdfs text file has extra square bracket in the beginning of the line and at the end of the line

```
hadoop dfs -cat op_dir/part*
[1,asdf,p1,Y]
[2,qwer,p2,N]
[3,,p5,Y]
```

Please suggest how to write the dataframe without the square brackets or parenthesis getting appended

Comment: which spark version?

Answer (score 0):

You could do this

```
df.repartition(5).map((row) => "%s,%s,%s,%s".format(row(0),row(1),row(2),row(3))).write.mode(SaveMode.Append).text(op_dir)
```

or this too

```
df.repartition(5).map((row) => row.mkString(",")).write.mode(SaveMode.Append).text(op_dir)
```

**NOTE**

If you want to write the (Start of heading) character you can try that in octal mode

```
\001
df.repartition(5).map((row) => row.mkString("\001")).write.mode(SaveMode.Append).text(op_dir)
```

but is deprecated, or in unicode

```
\u0001
df.repartition(5).map((row) => row.mkString("\u0001")).write.mode(SaveMode.Append).text(op_dir)
```

Comment: I am trying to write in save append mode with delimiter as "\\x01" (Ascii.SOH). This delim does not work

Comment: You could try in octal mode ````\001```` or unicode character ````\u0001````

Answer (score 0):

This will solve your problem-

```scala
   val df = Seq(
      ("a", 2, "c"),
      ("a", 2, "c"),
      ("a", 2, "c"),
      ("b", 2, "d"),
      ("b", 2, "d")
    ).toDF("col1", "col2", "col3")
    df.repartition(5).map((row)=>row.toString())
      .write.mode(SaveMode.Append)
      .text("/Users/sokale/models/x")

    /**
      * [a,2,c]
      * [b,2,d]
      */
    df.repartition(5).select(concat_ws(",", df.columns.map(col): _*))
      .write.mode(SaveMode.Append)
      .text("/Users/sokale/models/x2")

    /**
      * a,2,c
      * b,2,d
      */
```

### edit-1 (based on comment)

> **Use decimal for all control characters**

```
df.repartition(5).select(concat_ws("\001", df.columns.map(col): _*))
      .write.mode(SaveMode.Append)
      .text("/Users/sokale/models/x2")
```

Comment: I am trying to write in save append mode with delimiter as "\\x01" (Ascii.SOH). This delim does not work

Answer (score 0):

You can write in CSV format

```
df.repartition(5)
  .write.format("csv")
  .mode(SaveMode.Append)
  .save(path)
```

Comment: I am trying to write in save append mode with delimiter as "\\x01" (Ascii.SOH). This delim does not work